# Template instance before Meteor.startup or after it?

Tags: meteor

i put all my template files in client\

Should i bind events and handlebars helpers before Meteor.startup or after it ?
which one is better ? performance ?

```
Meteor.startup ->

    Template['module-demo'].lists = ->
        console.log 'test'
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do is settting all events and template helpers outside the startup method, as in the following code snippet.

```
Template.fileUpload.rendered = ->  
  filepicker.constructWidget document.getElementById('uploadWidget')

Template.fileUpload.events
  'change #uploadWidget' : (ev)->
    Archivos.insert(url: ev.files[0].url, timeStamp: new Date())

Meteor.startup ->
  Session.set "searchData", conCitasoAlertas()
  Session.set "paginaActual","home"
```